# Error al importar TkInter en Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Recibo un error al importar TkInter en Python 3.5. Éste es el mensaje de error que muestra:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 35, in 
>       import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
>
> ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tengo ubuntu 14.04 y ejecuto Python 3.5, ya probe instalar así:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk

sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

no sé qué sea el problema así trato de importarlo:

```
from tkinter import *
```

¿Por qué recibo ese error?¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Parece que la instalación de Python no incluía `tkinter`. Por favor, sigue los pasos que se indican [aquí](http://askubuntu.com/a/543486). Si tienes algún problema con ello avísanos.

Comment: yo probé esos pasos y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Te sigue dando el mismo error?

Comment: si sigue dando el mismo error y ya he probado varias cosas y nada aun

Comment: Una consulta, probaste como te indiqué mas abajo? Poniendo la primera letra en Mayuscula?

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, asegúrese de que tiene instalado python-support :

```
sudo apt-get install python-support
```

Tengo una pregunta. Estas usando un IDE o terminal?

Comment: Estoy utilizando el terminal

Answer (score 0):

A partir de python 3.x es Tkinter en vez de tkinter. Probá y avísanos por favor